# UITextView drawing improperly on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

This code:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, 80.0f)];
[textView setText:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."];
[textView setEditable:NO];
[self addSubview:textView];
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[textView setText:[textView.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"\nHello!"]];
[textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Will cause the `UITextView` to draw improperly at the bottom. It seems that iOS 7 does not increase the `contentSize` when `scrollEnabled` is false. This code would work fine in iOS 6, though. Is there something that I can do to fix this? I need scroll disabled, otherwise it will scroll back to the top when the text is added, which is not what I want.

Comment: try to setContentInset, [textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-45, 0, 5,0)];

Comment: UITextView shouldn't scroll to the top when adding text, even without disabling scrollEnabled to NO. Are you sure something else isn't causing that behavior?

Comment: @Keller yes, I'm sure that I am not doing anything different. I'm using the `setText` setter method. Is there a different/proper way to go about it?

Comment: I am having the same problem...as soon as I disable `scrollEnabled`, the text is cropped.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. Here's an ugly temporary hack FWIW:

```
NSAttributedString* text = textView.attributedText;
_textView.text = @"";
_textView.attributedText = text;
```

This seems to force the resizing and redraw.